# awk script not behaving correctly when run over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, awk

When running an awk script via ssh, I'm getting output which would more correctly be filtered:

```
$ ssh -q hostname '(awk "!/^#/ && \$3 ~ /ext/ && \$2 != "/" && \$2 != "/opt" { print \$2 }" /proc/mounts)'
/
/boot
/opt
/apps
/log
/data 

$ ssh -q hostname 'awk "!/^#/ && \$3 ~ /ext/ && \$2 != "/" && \$2 != "/opt" { print \$2 }" /proc/mounts'
/
/boot
/opt
/apps
/log
/data
```

Comment: `&&` isn't actually part of the problem here at all -- it's an awk operator in this context, not a bash operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to debug it is to use `eval` and `echo` on your command argument:

```
eval 'echo "!/^#/ && \$3 ~ /ext/ && \$2 != "/" && \$2 != "/opt" { print \$2 }"'
```

Output:

```
!/^#/ && $3 ~ /ext/ && $2 != / && $2 != /opt { print $2 }
```

Which shows that it's not a valid awk command argument. You still need to add the quotes:

```
eval 'echo "!/^#/ && \$3 ~ /ext/ && \$2 != \"/\" && \$2 != "\"/opt\"" { print \$2 }"'
```

Output:

```
!/^#/ && $3 ~ /ext/ && $2 != "/" && $2 != "/opt" { print $2 }
```

Which seems correct. Now putting it all together:

```
ssh -q hostname 'awk "!/^#/ && \$3 ~ /ext/ && \$2 != \"/\" && \$2 != "\"/opt\"" { print \$2 }" /proc/mounts'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, great answer. Very helpful with debugging option as well.

Answer (score 3):

Passing your code in as a quoted heredoc avoids having it parsed by the remote shell before being passed to awk:

```
ssh -q hostname 'awk -f - /proc/mounts' <<'EOF'
  !/^#/ && $3 ~ /ext/ && $2 != "/" && $2 != "/opt" { print $2 }
EOF
```